# At most how many unit circles can be inscribed in an ellipse?

Tags: geometry

By inscribed I mean when circle touches ellipse at 2 points. I think answer is 2 and I have an example, but I can't prove why we can't inscribe 3 circles, can someone help?

Comment: You can’t inscribe _any_ unit circles in the ellipse $4x^2+9y^2=1$, so there must be some other conditions on the ellipse.

Comment: @amd I want maximum number of circles that can be inscribed in _some_ ellipse, not _any_ ellipse.

Comment: @3zp I think you've misinterpreted the first comment.

Comment: Also, for larger ellipses, can't you "inscribe" as many circles as you want?

Comment: Please provide some more conditions to your problem.

Comment: Is the question whether we can inscribe 3 or more unit circles in the *same* ellipse? [Question seem unclear as written-- would appreciate clarification.]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).